# cannot authorize using Rest-Assured

Tags: jira, rest-assured, authorize

400 error cannot understand where is mistake in code
I used Rest-assured documentation
https://www.toolsqa.com/rest-assured/post-request-using-rest-assured/

Please help with this question

```
package forth;

import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.Assert;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import io.restassured.response.Response;


import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class zero {

    @Test
    public void RegistrationSuccessful()
    {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        RestAssured.baseURI ="url";
        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();

        JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
        requestParams.put("useremail", "my login"); 
        requestParams.put("api_token", "my token");
        request.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.body(requestParams.toJSONString());
        Response response = request.post("/rest/auth/1/session");

        int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
        Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, "201");
        String successCode = response.jsonPath().get("SuccessCode");
        Assert.assertEquals( "Correct Success code was returned", successCode, "OPERATION_SUCCESS");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the API documentation of the API that you want to test here? t will help to identify the cause for the error.

Comment: Are you sure your base uri is this one  - RestAssured.baseURI ="URL"; ? Seems like you need to change this to a proper one. This way you are hitting the POST endpoint as "url/rest/auth/1/session", maybe you just put it as an example to not reveal the endpoint. If that's the case then, print your request body, use postman to hit the endpoint with the same request body and then check if issue persists.

Comment: Add  ```System.out.println(response.prettyPrint());```  to see the error message as well. You can also add request.log().all() to see exactly what you are sending to the api.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, always try opening the end point url in new tab of browser, if it doesn't give any error then, it is an indication that we can use it. If browser displays something like "This site can't be reached", then it is not a valid end point or server is not up and running for respective end point.

In case of toolsqa website, in starting few pages endpoints are not working. I sent a message to Virender to look into this issue, but unfortunately no response.

I suggest you to learn rest assured from makeseleniumeasy website as per my personal experience.

Comment: I am hoping you have updated the baseUri in the code with actual end point url, not just "url".

Answer (score 0):

Its very important to check if the api requires form params or body params.
form-params are intended to be used with content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" (a form)
body-params are intended to use for parameters which are also going to be located in the body with other content-types (application/json)